# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_WebEngage

Tags: ios, react-native, webengage

I'm facing this issue while building react native ios project.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_WebEngage", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in webengageBridge(WEGWebEngageBridge.o)

react-native: "0.67.2"
react-native-webengage: "1.2.13"

Does anyone have good luck in fixing this issue?

I tried adding the WebEngage.framework in Link Binary With Libraries. But error remains to be there.